# Multi-tasking with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, ios4, multitasking

I have an audio app using AVAudioPlayer build for iPhone 3.x, now I would like to harness the multi-tasking capability in iOS 4 such that it can play music at the background. I tried to search for sample code but no luck. Can anyone help showing me how to enable AVAudioPlayer for background playing in iOS 4?

thanks.

Comment: Look for "executing code in background" in this: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf